# How to find the version of module in Node Js

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm having a problem, I installed a module but I want to know the version so I can added to the package json of my project.

Comment: `cat node_modules/theModuleName/package.json | grep version`. Or you can just install it again with `npm install -S module`, which saves it in `package.json` automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install your module like this

```
npm install your_module --save
```

and this will install the module and save it in your `package.json` at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm list` which will show the version numbers of your locally installed modules.

You can also use `npm list --depth=0` to fetch versions of modules without dependencies.

`npm install <module_name> --save` will save data in `package.json` **only** if you have permission writes for the file(On *nix system I face the problem at times, so thought to mention it).